# Accessing Office 365 site collection without microsoft login: Access site anonymously

Tags: office-365, site-collection

I am creating a sharepoint site on which users will be able to register and login. I want this site to be accessed by any user on the internet. Also, I need a custom domain like https://www.my-website.com

When I hit this URL, it should open my sharepoint website.

Thanks

Note: It's office 365 sharepoint online. Not the on-premises.

Comment: Public sites (anonymously accessible sites) are not available in SharePoint online anymore

Answer (score 4):

Public SharePoint Online websites that allow for custom domains are no longer supported. You'll need to host something somewhere else. See the exhaustive guidance here, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3027254.